# How do I write a wait command in selenium that allows a website to finish editing it's select items?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, bots

I'm writing a bot in Python - Selenium that needs to choose things in a drop-down Select menu. The website in question seems to be initializing it's select drop down items with only 1 value: 1. My wait command

`wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "select")))`

won't cut it for this, it will only see the initial option of 1.

So I tried to wait until a 2nd option appears under it's select

`wait.until(lambda d: d.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'option:nth-child(2)'))`

but that always times out. This confuses me because this code executes fine:

`wait.until(lambda d: d.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'option:nth-child(1)'))`

Why am I timing out? I can see selects with 10 options as soon as the page is loaded.
I've also tried Expected Conditions looking for the value or text of 2:

`wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.TAG_NAME, "option"),'2'))`

times out

`wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.TAG_NAME, "option"),'1'))`

has no trouble finding an option element with a value of 1.

I've tried a lot of iterations on this. Am I not understanding how wait commands and expected conditions are supposed to work?

Comment: It's hard to say what the issue might be without some experimentation. Perhaps the DOM is changing dynamically over time? Perhaps the second value isn't considered "visible" until the drop-down is expanded and scrolled to the correct position? etc

Comment: Are you able to share the url, and show us where the problem is happening?

Comment: I've got it now. It wasn't just not visible, it wasn't updating the options at all until the drop down menu is clicked on.